# I have a list of unique id in which i want to implement a counter for each of the id data will be refreshed every 10 mins

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

Data will be refreshed every 10 mins and the count has to change accordingly.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readfile = require('readfile');

function readFile(file_name) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(file_name, (err, data) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve(data);
        });
    });
}

async function execute(file_name) {
    try {
        const file_data = await readFile(file_name);
        const records = JSON.parse(file_data);
        return records.map(single_record => single_record.rdid);
    }
    catch(e) {
         // error handling
    }
}

execute("data.json").then(push => console.log(push));
```

This is my JSON file

```
[

    {"edid":"r7vr8r", "rdid":"86596", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"v8r48e", "rdid":"98525", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"948rcv", "rdid":"12585", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"d39d38", "rdid":"12585", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"f44914", "rdid":"86596", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"r7vr8r", "rdid":"86596", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"v8r48e", "rdid":"98525", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"948rcv", "rdid":"86596", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"r8v9ee", "rdid":"98525", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"d39d38", "rdid":"98525", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"f44914", "rdid":"12585", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"r7vr8r", "rdid":"12585", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"v8r48e", "rdid":"98525", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"948rcv", "rdid":"12585", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"r8v9ee", "rdid":"12585", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"d39d38", "rdid":"98525", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"},
    {"edid":"f44914", "rdid":"12585", "rssi":"15", "batt":"1.35"}
]
```

This is my current output.

```
[
  '86596', '98525', '12585',
  '12585', '86596', '86596',
  '98525', '86596', '98525',
  '98525', '12585', '12585',
  '98525', '12585', '12585',
  '98525', '12585'
]
```

but instead of this i would like to have something like:

```
98525: 6
12585: 7
86596: 4
```

Data on the JSON file will be refreshed every 10 mins

Comment: [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) will let you construct a result from the loop

Answer (score 0):

This could work out

**Using `Map`**

```js
let counter = new Map()

records.forEach(single_record => {
  const n = parseInt(single_record.rdid)
  if (!counter.has(n)) {
    counter.set(n, 1);
  }
  else {
    counter.set(n, counter.get(n) + 1);
  }
})

counter.forEach((value, key) => {
  console.log(key + ":" + value)
})
```

**Using `Object`**

```js
let counter = {}

records.forEach(single_record => {
  if (!counter.hasOwnProperty(single_record.rdid)) {
    counter[single_record.rdid] = 1;
  }
  else {
    counter[single_record.rdid]++;
  }
})

console.log(counter)
```

Comment: it says that "records" is undefined. Are there any more lines that i have to add to make it work?

Comment: You should run that after `const records = JSON.parse(file_data);`

Comment: do i have to define 'records' if yes, how do i do it

Comment: In your `execute` function, `records` already is defined.

Answer (score 0):

simple get your return data as:

```
uniqueCount = [
  '86596', '98525', '12585',
  '12585', '86596', '86596',
  '98525', '86596', '98525',
  '98525', '12585', '12585',
  '98525', '12585', '12585',
  '98525', '12585'
];
var count = {};
uniqueCount.forEach(function(i) { 
   count[i] = (count[i]||0) + 1;
});
console.log(count);

// result will be {12585: 7, 86596: 4, 98525: 6}
```

Comment: thanks, this data will be refreshed every 10 mins so the count will always be different. Any idea how?

Comment: no problem just store the data result in a global variable.

Comment: is there a way to link the output of the JSON file to 'uniqueCount' instead of having to key in all the value?

Comment: your already doing that, execute("data.json").then(data => console.log(data));

Comment: the output is 12344,12343,12433,16543,12565,14543 instead of 12123: 3, 45362: 7 54630: 6 for example